# Limit tags on REST endpoints

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer

Absolutely love micrometer. Running a spring boot JAX RS app. Am using datadog registry and wanted to time some service methods. I saw all rest end points are timed and detail sent - thats great.

However here is the issue I am facing. If I have a GET call that takes a path param, for example `/employees/{empId}`, And If I have a million users in the system, then I guess we will have 1 million tag combinations pushed to datadog. So question is how to get around this. In this case I am only interested in all of the GET calls and not a specific call to get a specific employee. So how do I also tell micrometer/spring-boot to use the pattern rather than actual values. (I am not using @Timed on the JAX-RS resource classes. Is that the way to go ?)

Comment: Can you include the code for the `/employees/{empId}` mapping?

Comment: What JAX-RS implementation are you running? The second question: Which Spring-Boot version are you running? Dependant on these answers, I might be able to give some hints.